# chromium fails to start in headless mode `Error: Can't open display:` inside container

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When building a container to run some selenium tests I am trying to validate that chromium can be started in headless mode `chromium --headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage https://www.chromestatus.com/` only to be met with the following error.

`Error: Can't open display:`

The versions of chromeium and chromium driver I am using are

- Chromium `Version: 113.0.5672.63-1~deb11u1`
- Chromium-driver `Version: 113.0.5672.63-1~deb11u1`

the docker file I am buildign with is as follows

```
FROM python:3.9.15-bullseye

# development dependencies
ARG POETRY_FLAGS="-without dev"
ARG NPM_FLAGS="-omit=dev"
ARG WEBPACK_CONFIG="webpack.prod.js"
ARG NPM_SCRIPT="build"
ARG EXTRA_PACKAGES=""

WORKDIR /opt/discoverypage

ENV PYTHONPATH=/opt/discoverypage/src

RUN apt update && \
    apt upgrade --yes && \
    apt install --yes \
    curl ${EXTRA_PACKAGES}

(removed python code and poetry install)
```

Where extra packages will be equal to `firefox-esr chromium-browser chromium-driver`

When I try to execute the test cases with the following setup

```
@pytest.fixture
def chrome_web_driver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    # the shared memory in gitlab runners is tiny and is causing our browser to crash
    # so turn this off forcing /tmp to be used instead
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    yield web_driver

    web_driver.close()
```

I am met with the following error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I have tried installing `xvfb` but still see the same issue.

Comment: try using `pyvirtualdisplay`